# What is the correct way to compare different treatments at different concentrations?

Tags: anova, multiple-comparisons, post-hoc

I did an experiment where I am comparing control vs. three drug treatments, each at three different concentrations, and each concentration has 4 replicates. The outcome is signal intensity. I am unsure about the statistics to use.

The method I am currently using is:

1. **ANOVA** to look at whether signal intensity is significantly different
   based on treatment.
2. If significant, post-hoc analysis: I am using **pairwise t tests**, with Holm p-value adjustment method.
3. Look for p-values < 0.05 vs control in the pairwise t tests.

I am not sure because of the nature of my experiment which involves different concentrations, so I am not really comparing independent groups together. Should I perhaps consider each treatment as a separate experiment vs control?

Also, I am only interested in comparisons vs. control. I am not interested at this stage in comparing one treatment/concentration with another treatment/concentration. However, when I do the pairwise t tests, the p-values will be increased based on the number of comparisons I am doing, so including the ones I am not actually looking at.

The first method I was using is manually running t tests for each treatment/concentration vs control. But in addition to being long, it does not seem strict enough and/or to be the best possible use of my data...

Do you agree with my method? Should I change something?

Comment: Did you completely randomize the order of those 48 observations? If not, how did you proceed? It matters.

Comment: No, I did not. There are 40 observations (there was only one control, which is the highest concentration of what the drug is diluted into). They are in the order: Control/Drug 1 concentration 1/Drug 1 concentration 2/Drug 1 concentration 3/Drug 2 concentration 1/ etc, you got it. I am using the average of each four replicates. Should have I randormised the order of these observations? Can you explain why it matters?

Comment: Did you do each set of 4 replicates consecutively within this plan?  Randomization is important because probability models are the basis for statistical inference. Without it, you have to hope there are no sources of bias. I wouldn’t trust your analysis to have much meaning. And I hope you ask a statistician before plunging into your next experiment.

Comment: [1/2] Ok I see what you are saying. I should have explained the experimental context a bit. These are cell cultures in a plate with 96 wells, not animals or patients. What could be randomised is which well is treated with which drug/concentration. This is not the case here as we try to have plate maps that are a bit more intuitive to prepare. Randomisation would create plates that are a nightmare to prepare, and we would probably end up making mistakes.

Comment: [2/2] I cannot think of much bias that could appear as cells are all from the same culture (and there are thousands of cells per well), all wells are treated almost at the same time, etc. The few bias that could appear, for example whether wells at the periphery of the plate would be biased for some reason, were checked on tens of plates in a process called uniformity assays. Does that answer your question a bit better? And do you have an opinion on the statistics I am doing? Thanks a lot for your input!

Comment: There are other kinds of randomization besides complete randomization — and corresponding models — that could address practical concerns about implementation. I interpret your comments about previous uniformity tests as saying that you really don’t buy into the ideas behind statistical methods. Thus I think the best way to proceed is to not use any. Just tabulate and/or graph your results. You won’t get me to agree that any kind of t test or anova is justified.

Comment: Ok... I'm sorry if my comments lead you to interpret that. This was obviously not the message as I would not be here digging into which specific statistical method I should use if I was not interested in their assumptions. Here are the first three papers I could find when googling 'cell culture screening', please tell me if you see anything about any kind of well randomisation in the Methods, I do not see any. Could you give examples of bias that I could include by proceeding like I do? I am genuinely trying to understand the problem here. Thanks again for your time @rvl

Comment: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5030729/

http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.601.2977&rep=rep1&type=pdf

https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166354217305958?via%3Dihub
I am still interested in your opinion about the statistical methods if you are willing to help. Thanks a lot @rvl.